# Chrome: mobile vs desktop differences

Tags: google-chrome, safari, mobile-safari, google-apps

EDITED: Let me expand the scope of this question to browser capabilities wrt HTML5 and Javascript on destop vs mobile platforms. The original question is below.

What's the difference in the capabilities b/w Chrome for desktop (Mac/Windows/Linux) and that for mobile (Android/iOS). For example, look at a Google Apps spreadsheet on your tablet vs on your desktop and you see that the mobile version seems "limited"? The surface area is limited for phones admittedly but why serve up mobile version for a tablet? What are those limitations  (forget extensions when answering this question).

Comment: iOs chrome can't do WebGL.

Comment: @zero298 Let me edit this question to handle browsers in general: desktop vs mobile?

Answer (score 2):

The differences are decided by every website, "what are the diff..." can't be answered in general.

Your browser tells the website User-agent string, which allows the website to decide if it wants to serve a mobile version, that is typically reduced in features. Often there's a link in the footer or so, that lets you switch back to the desktop version.

Also, most today's mobile browsers have a setting like "desktop version". This changes the user agent string to something that makes websites think it's a desktop browser.